# How I do for my project using Local IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, windows-8.1

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, Windows 8.1 and IIS 8.0.
In properties settings, I have set the server to Local IIS and I set the project url  to localhost/myProject.
When I debug the project I get the following error shown below:

Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server could not find the requested resource.

### Click Help for more information.

### OK   Help

and when I start without debugging I get this error:

**Error HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden**

can somenone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to give proper permissions to the directory containing your application. Give read, write, and modify permissions to IUSR and IIS_USERS. This should help to resolve your issue. Did your application work using IIS Express? If it didn't work using IIS Express then I'll need more specific information on the issue you're running into.